# Find the solid bounded by the surfaces $z=3x^2+3y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z=4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I want to solve this integral I believe $\int\int_S\int_{3x^2+3y^2}^{4-x^2-y^2} dzdA$

Which should be $4\int\int_S 1-x^2-y^2 dA$

So what I am trying to do is solve this in polar coordinates. $\int\int_S (1-r^2)r drd\theta$

but I'm having trouble figuring out the bounds of the integrals since I can't really draw this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the surfaces we're working with are defined in terms of $x^2+y^2$ - no instances of either $x$ or $y$ alone. So, then, it's all radially symmetric. When we convert to polar coordinates, our $\theta$ bounds will simply be the whole way around $0$ to $2\pi$.

In $r$ - well, how big is $r$ when the two surfaces cross? For what value of $r$ is $4-r^2=3r^2$? Our bounds will run from zero to there.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how you can be sure that it wouldn't be necessary to break it into sums?

Comment: Where would we? We only break where something important changes. The only place where things change is the circle where we switch which surface is on top. Inside, that's a bounded region we can find the volume of. Outside, that's an unbounded region with infinite volume, and the only sensible thing we can do is declare that it's not the region we're interested in.